# Converting odd date format into actual date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have general formatting coming across as 'Sep 30 2021'.  How can I easily convert this to read 2021-09-01?  I have attempted to do so the normal routes but it appears I need a formula to solve this issue.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information. Please edit your question to include **specifically** what you have tried, and what the results are.  Include your windows short date settings, language, what happened when you tested for whether the date was text or numeric, the specifics of what you consider "normal routes", how the date was inputted, etc.

Comment: Since you don't appear to be an Excel O365 customer, this will be a tiny bit harder but by no means difficult.  But we will need to understand some specific assumptions about formatting.  Are the days *always* expressed as 2 digits, so the first day is `01`?  Is the month *always* expressed as the usual 3-letter abbreviations?  If these are both true this is a very straightforward formula.  Also, if you have O365, it gets even easier.

Comment: Saying you've tried, without sharing how makes us having to test the same potentially. Provided that you give any example data at least. Otherwise we're unable to test anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can do this by =Text(Column, "yyyy-mm-dd")